# “'AttributeError: ‘WSGIRequest’ object has no attribute ‘is_ajax’” when trying to use django with google map api when developing a website

Tags: python, django, ajax, google-maps

I am currently following along with a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCn8WND-JpU) that utilizes Django, python, and front-end languages to develop a website with Google Maps API.

This is for a project I want to pursue, but when I finished all the code it gave an error of

```
‘WSGIRequest’ object has no attribute ‘is_ajax’ when trying to get past the sign-in page.
```

I reached out to the YouTuber and he gracefully told me I needed to replace the `'request.is_ajax()'` to `request.META.` on the `views.py`. I tried doing that but it is still not working.

Could anyone be able to help me resolve this problem?

Here is the file he told me I needed to change the is_ajax: https://github.com/bobby-didcoding/did_django_google_api_tutorial/blob/main/users/views.py

If anyone needs more information, please let me know! I 100% followed along the tutorial from start to finish.

Comment: `.is_ajax()` has been removed from the request object, especially since that simply can not be tested effectively and is thus misleading.

Comment: The best way is likely to make two views, one for the AJAX requests, and one for the HTML handler.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I did not know that! So is that why request.META. should be used? I think making two views will help me as well!